# Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in <b>/homepages/1/d835516322/htdocs/vitruvium/first.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />

Tags: php, command-line, paypal

I have this PayPal documentation file, which i need to run through the command line, everything seems ok, but i am running into some trouble.
Any clue what is going on and how to fix it? I read something about the \r\n of windows and transforming it to \n, but i am not sure what does it mean.

```
<?php

// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files and classes to your autoloader
require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';

// 2. Provide your Secret Key. Replace the given one with your app clientId, and Secret
// https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'my CLient id',     // ClientID
        'My client secret'      // ClientSecret
    )
);

// 3. Lets try to create a Payment
// https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create
$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setTotal('1.00');
$amount->setCurrency('USD');

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("https://neovinci.es/success.html")
    ->setCancelUrl("https://neovinci.es/cancel.html");

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

// 4. Make a Create Call and print the values
try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
    echo $payment;

    echo "\n\nRedirect user to approval_url: " . $payment->getApprovalLink() . "\n";
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    // This will print the detailed information on the exception.
    //REALLY HELPFUL FOR DEBUGGING
    echo $ex->getData();
}
```

But when i run it from the command line always appears these errors:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in <b>/homepages/1/d835516322/htdocs/vitruvium/first.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

And

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/homepages/1/d835516322/htdocs/vitruvium/first.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish or what your error is about, but the PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK ; you should not be using it for anything.

Comment: Thank you, I started working today so i did not know much about it, but i wont be using it anymore